# Why -20dB is taken as the standard rejection ratio for optical mode rejection in multimode waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, error-analysis, fiber-optics, waveguide

In case of multimode waveguide to demonstrate perfect mode rejection, I saw researchers use boundary of -20dB. If mode power at output is less then -20dB, it is considered as fully rejected/filter out. But why -20dB & what is the reference of that logic?here's a image from a published research work. Link:-https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-42-18-3686[image: https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-42-18-3686]

Comment: Well, what level would you consider appropriate? If you can't differentiate at -20dB you have other problems in your system. Or would you prefer -10dB?

Comment: $-20dB\equiv 1\%$